# SwiftUI: Setting Picker selection to last in dynamic array

Tags: swiftui, picker

I have a Picker in a detail view that changes the subviews accordingly. I can set it to the first in the array (Index 0), but for the user it would be more logical if it defaulted to the last.

```
struct ViewDetail: View {

   @State public var selectedYearIndex = 0

.
.
.


Picker(selection: $selectedYearIndex, label: PickerLabel()) {
                    Group {
                        ForEach(0 ..< yearArray.count)) {
                            Text(self.yearArray[$0].description).tag($0)
                        }
                    }
                }

.
.
.

}
```

Can anyone suggest a way to default the Picker Selection to the last index in an array of variable size?

Thoughts?

Comment: Where and how is your `yearArray` declared?

Answer (score 2):

I was able to resolve this by adding the following to the view:

```
.onAppear {
            if self.selectedYearIndex == 0 {
                self.selectedYearIndex = (yearArray.count - 1)
            }
        }
```

This work consistently, and did not affect the functionality of the picker.